Trigonometric function radian problem.
My native language is Chinese, so I use a translation machine.
I know when $x$ is used in degrees, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=\frac{\pi}{180}$.
And when $x$ is used in radians, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=1$.
Looking at the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=1$ ($x$ is used radians), Fraction $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ represents $\frac{\sin (x_{(rad)})}{x_{(rad)}}$. But at the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=\frac{\pi}{180}$($x$ is used degress), Why does fraction $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ not represent $\frac{\sin (x_{(degrees)})}{x_{(degrees)}}$?
Many people say that angles cannot be placed in the denominator (angles cannot be calculated), But if angles and radians can be converted into each other, So for $\frac{\sin (x_{(rad)})}{x_{(rad)}}$, $x_{(rad)}$ in the denominator can also represent an angle, right?
I feel very confused.
Hope you can understand my question, thank you.

See this answer.

You might find this post helpful

Here too. One of these could probably be chosen as a duplicate. (I don't fault the OP for not finding these if English is not their native language.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
